# Multivariable polynomial decomposition

Tags: polynomials

There is a beautiful theorem that allows us to decompose a polynomial of several variables into the sum  of polynomials of a single variable.

> Let $P_{N}(x)$ be a multivarible polynomial of degree $N$, where $x = (x_1,...,x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Let $\Omega$ be a finite subset of the unit sphere $S^{n-1} = \{ \omega \in  \mathbb{R}^n \mid \omega \cdot \omega = 1 \} $ such that 
>   $$| \Omega | \geq  { N + n -1 \choose n-1 }$$
>   and points in $\Omega$ are in general position. Then there exist polynomials $P_{N,\omega}$ of a single variable of degree $N$ such that
>   $$
>    P_N(x) = \sum\limits_{\omega \in \Omega} P_{N,\omega} (\omega \cdot x)
> $$

In other words this theorem allows us to represent a polynomial of a vector variable $x$ as a sum of polynomials of its projections $\omega \cdot x$ on a finite number of directions. My question is how to proove this theorem?

Comment: Do you recall where you came across this theorem, or what it's called?

Comment: @anon, this property of a set $\Omega$ is called $N$-solvability. I came across it in one paper on multidimensional moment's problem. I found some references on T. Natterer's book "The mathematics of computerized tomography". In this book the similar property is called $N$-resolvability and it is related with spherical harmonics.

Comment: 1. Can you give an example? 2.Can this be extended to $x\in \mathbb{C}^n$? 3. Would it further simplify the result, if $P_N(x)$ would be homogenous? @anon, can you help? I would be glad to read your opinion...

Comment: I have a related problem. Did you make any progress on this question?

Comment: @tgoossens I think that unfortunately the answer is negative

Comment: @Appliqué Sorry but is it thus a theorem or is it not true? In your question you call it a theorem but it does not seem so after the discussion. Could you please change your question to make clear if it is or not a theorem after all?

Comment: @Hvjurthuk It is a theorem